How to upgrade GTK4 to specific version
I've recently started my journey with Python and GTK library.
First Glade and GTK3 now I've updated to GTK4 and Cambalache.
However..
Developing new UI and trying to run my first initial draft of UI, threw up and error:
gi.repository.GLib.GError: gtk-builder-error-quark: ./src/[my_app_name].ui:6:1 Required GTK version 4.14, current version is 4.10 (7)
I've changed to 4.10 within Cambalache but received error that Templated are not suppoted within GTK 4.10, so I've switched back to 4.14.
BUT I couldn't switch to 4.14 version at main library.
What am I mising of which I don't have any idea?
How can I change base version of GTK to use within project?
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04

What version of Ubuntu are you using, it matters.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04
